# Dúvida loop jogo da velha (Python)

Tags: python

Boa tarde, gente. Esse é um código que eu vi que reproduz um jogo da velha. Será que alguém poderia me esclarecer como está funcionando o Loop da função evaluate e play_game? Especificamente essa parte `for player in [1, 2]:`. Muito obrigado.

```
def create_board():
    board = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)
    return board

def place(board, player, position):
    if board[position] == 0:
        board[position] = player
        return (board)

def possibilities(board):     
    return list(zip(*np.where(board == 0)))

def random_place(board, player):
    escolhe = random.choice(possibilities(board))
    return place(board,player,escolhe)

def row_win(board, player):
    return np.any(np.all(board==player,axis=1))

def col_win(board, player):
    return np.any(np.all(board==player,axis=0))    

def diag_win(board, player):
     if np.any(np.all(np.diagonal(board)==player)) or np.any(np.all(np.fliplr(board).diagonal() == player)):
        return True
     else:
        return False    

def evaluate(board):
    winner = 0
    for player in [1, 2]:
        if row_win(board, player) or col_win(board, player) or diag_win(board, player):
            winner = player
    if np.all(board != 0) and winner == 0:
        winner = -1
    return winner

def play_game():
    board = create_board()
    winner = 0
    while winner == 0:
        for player in [1, 2]:
            random_place(board, player)
            winner = evaluate(board)
            if winner != 0:
                break
    return winner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde,
Vamos começar pela função *play_game*, pois, ela é nossa função principal.

A função *play_game* possui 2 loops:

`while winner == 0:` Responsável por fazer o jogo funcionar, pois, ele irá executar todas as funções até que o jogo possua um vencedor `winner = player` ou todo o tabuleiro seja preenchido `winner = -1`.

`for player in [1, 2]:` Responsável pela iteração dos jogadores. Esse laço vai ser executado 2 vezes, uma para cada item contido no array `[1, 2]`. Na primeira iteração player irá receber o valor 1 (primeiro item contido no array), na segunda iteração ele receberá 2 (segundo item contido no array).

Obs: A forma que o laço `for player in [1, 2]:` para a funcionalidade **evaluate** é executada é a mesma da funcionalidade *play_game*, a única coisa que muda são as chamadas realizadas dentro do laço.

Caso ainda possua duvidas, execute alguns testes alterando o código a seguir em um novo arquivo:

```
for i in [1, 2]:
    print(i)
```